# how to get 1st column value using partition

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table looks like this

```
CREATE TABLE myTable
(
    userid      text,
    webid         text,
    "timestamp" timestamp
);

INSERT INTO myTable
    ("userid", "webid", "timestamp")
VALUES ('A', '34', '2023-01-31 17:34:49.000'),
       ('A', '73', '2023-01-31 17:34:50.000'),
       ('A', '97', '2023-01-31 17:34:58.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:02.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:07.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:18.000'),
       ('A', '17', '2023-01-31 17:35:30.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:35:37.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:35:38.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:35:41.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:35:42.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:37:10.000'),
       ('A', '1', '2023-01-31 17:37:12.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:37:14.000'),
       ('A', '77', '2023-01-31 17:37:15.000'),
       ('B', '33', '2023-01-31 06:37:15.000'),
       ('B', '56', '2023-01-31 06:40:15.000')
  ;
```

| userid | webid | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 17:34:49 |
| A | 73 | 2023-01-31 17:34:50 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:30 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:15 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 |

The correct output I want is this:

| userid | webid | timestamp | first_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 17:34:49 | 2023-01-31 17:34:49 |
| A | 73 | 2023-01-31 17:34:50 | 2023-01-31 17:34:50 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:30 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:15 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 |

first_ts means first timestamp. If a userid visits consecutive webid, their first_ts should be the first timestamp of this webid. If the userid visits webid let's say webid = 77 and jumps to another webid = 1 and then jumps back to webid = 77, the first_ts should be refreshed, it won't be the very first one. I used following code to do that, but unable to get correct first_ts for userid who jumps back to previous webid.

```
select userid, webid, 
lag(webid,1) over(partition by userid order by timestamp desc) as next_webid,
lag(webid,1) over(partition by userid order by timestamp asc) as previous_webid,
timestamp,
case when webid = next_webid then first_value(timestamp) over(partition by userid, webid order by timestamp) 
     when webid = next_webid and webid = previous_webid then first_value(timestamp) over(partition by userid, webid order by timestamp) 
     when webid = previous_webid then first_value(timestamp) over(partition by userid, webid order by timestamp) 
     else timestamp
end as first_ts
from myTable 
order by userid, timestamp;
```

this wrong query will return output

| userid | webid | timestamp | first_ts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 34 | 2023-01-31 17:34:49 | 2023-01-31 17:34:49 |
| A | 73 | 2023-01-31 17:34:50 | 2023-01-31 17:34:50 |
| A | 97 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 | 2023-01-31 17:34:58 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:07 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:18 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 17 | 2023-01-31 17:35:30 | 2023-01-31 17:35:02 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:35:38 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:35:42 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:10 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 1 | 2023-01-31 17:37:12 | 2023-01-31 17:35:37 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:14 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| A | 77 | 2023-01-31 17:37:15 | 2023-01-31 17:35:41 |
| B | 33 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 | 2023-01-31 06:37:15 |
| B | 56 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 | 2023-01-31 06:40:15 |

in row 12, 13, 14, 15, the first_ts is wrong.
Anyone knows how to modify the query to get correct first_ts? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem.  One solution uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid ORDER BY timestamp) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userid, webid ORDER BY timestamp) rn2
    FROM myTable
)

SELECT userid, webid, timestamp,
       MIN(timestamp) OVER (PARTITION BY userid, webid, rn1 - rn2) AS first_ts
FROM cte
ORDER BY userid, timestamp;
```

The idea here is to use the row number difference to form a pseudo group, which is defined by the `userid`, `webid`, and `rn1 - rn2`.  We then take the minimum timestamp for each such group/island to find the `first_ts`.  To get a better understanding of how difference in row numbers works, just run `SELECT * FROM cte` and check the results.

Comment: hi, I am trying to cooperate 30 minutes rule on first_st, there will be one corner case like the example here won't pass. The example is here: https://dbfiddle.uk/D4xqViDn                                                                                                   I use your query to cooperate 30 minutes rule, the row 17 will have wrong first_ts. do you know how to modify the code?

Comment: 30 minute rule totally changes the question and invalidates my answer.  I suggest asking a new question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75692009/how-to-get-1st-column-value-using-partition-with-30-minutes-rule  I post right here. if you can help, very appreciate it.